# How to put multiple dataTables in one page?

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, bootstrap-4

Hello I'm in the middle of a Intranet development and i'm using DataTable in 4 different tables but just one works well, how can i change this situation?

PHP Page(Have some words in Portuguese):

https://pastebin.com/xutdL6bc

And this is the JavaScript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

If i change the class of the table the "beauty" will not work

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE

I have looked up the API and I found the documentation that discusses having two tables. They achieve this based on the class of those tables. So in your case it would be `table.beauty`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.beauty').DataTable();
} );
```

Then get the table with the needed class:

```
<table id="" class="beauty" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

For more documentation look under [their docs](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html). It has all the information on there that you will need to get started with the code.

---

No, it would not, because in your current code changing the class will do absolutely nothing since you are calling the element by its `id` (`#example`). You are calling the jQuery element by ID value: `#example`. In practice you would have to change the JavaScript if you want the code to be applied by class.

```
// only the element with the id of example
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

If you want to get based on class change the `#` to a `.`. That would look like:

```
// any element with the class of example
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.example').dataTable();
} );
```

---

**NOTE:** Your code is using `mysql` functions which are depricated, I know you were not asking about that; but if you are learning PHP I recommend you learn to use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) would be far more beneficial.

Comment: Note that depending on the configuration options passed to the DataTable, there may need to be 4 separate calls. `$("#example").dataTable(); $("#example2").dataTable();...etc.`

Comment: That is true, but he changes to class names than that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can't necessarily do it in 1 call, because the configuration for each table may be (and is likely to be) different.

Comment: Como assim? Are you getting errors? Look under your console for any error messages. @RafaelBreno

Comment: I've tried to change to $(".example") and doing the same in 4 different calls(changing the id in the php file too)

Comment: Did you add the class to `example`? If the table(s) doesn't have the class then the script will overlook it @RafaelBreno

Comment: @Samuel o que está acontecendo é o seguinte, o dataTable me permite criar um tabela com paginação e pesquisa de informações dentro da tabela, porém tenho em 1 página 4 tabela diferentes, e apenas na 1° que funciona a paginação e pesquisa, nas outras 3 não aparece paginação e nem o campo "search".

Comment: That makes sense. Have you tried instead giving each table an unique ID and then creating a new js block for each of them? @RafaelBreno

Comment: What's the name of the JS library? I can have a look at it. @RafaelBreno